# Sense of the second term of $X_t = X_0 + \int_{0}^t f(s, \omega)ds + \int_{0}^t g(s, \omega)dW_s$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Suppose that $W_t$ is a Brownian motion. Consider

$$X_t = X_0 + \int_{0}^t f(s, \omega)ds + \int_{0}^t g(s, \omega)dW_s$$

The question is about the second term  $\int_{0}^t f(s, \omega)ds $.

We usually imply that the integral $\int_{0}^t f(s, \omega)ds $ is pathwise (it means that for any fixed $\omega = \omega_0$ we have $\int_{0}^t f(s, \omega_0)ds$). But what exacltly does this term mean?

In books "Topics in stochastic process" by R.B. Ash, M. F. Gardner, (p.226) and "Theory and Statistical Applications of Stochastic Processes" (p.203) by Y. Mishura and G. Shevchenko  it's said that
$P( \int_{0}^t |f(s, \omega)|ds < \infty) = 1$ and $f(s, \omega)$ progressively measurbale.

In the book "Theory of Stochastic Processes: With Applications to Financial Mathematics and Risk Theory (Problem Books in Mathematics)" (p.194) it's said that $f(s, \omega)$ is measurable, adapted to filtration and $P( \int_{0}^t |f(s, \omega)|ds < \infty) = 1$.

In the book "Introduction to Stochastic Intergation" by Hui-Hsiung Kuo, 2006, p.95, (in a special case $\int_{0}^t f''(W(s))ds$)  it's said that the $ \int_{0}^t f(s, \omega)ds$  is a Riemann integral for each sample path of $W_s$.

The question appeared in connection with the next fact.  In the book: "Theory of Random Processes in Examples and Problems." by B. M. Miller and A. S. Pankov it's said that the integral $\int_{0}^t f(s, \omega)ds $ is $L_2$ intergral, i.e. the $L_2$-limit of $\sum_{i=1}^n f(s_i, \omega) (t_i  - t_{i-1})$.

So, we may create several defintions of $\int_{0}^t f(s, \omega)ds$.

**Defintion 1:**
It's Lebesgue pathwise integral + we imply that $P( \int_{0}^t |f(s, \omega)|ds < \infty) = 1$ and $f(s, \omega)$ progressively measurbale.

**Defintion 2:**
It's Lebesgue pathwise integral + we imply that $P( \int_{0}^t |f(s, \omega)|ds < \infty) = 1$ and $f(s, \omega)$ is measurable and adopted to filtration.

**Defintion 3:** It's $L_2$-limit of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_{s_i} (t_i  - t_{i-1})$ (Riemann $L_2$ integral).

**Defintion 4a:** It's pathwise Riemann  intergal for all $\omega$.

**Defintion 4b:** It's pathwise Riemann  intergal for  $\omega \in \Omega^*: P(\Omega^*) = 1$.

I got used to defintion 1. The question is why another definitions do not work? (or if somebody disagree with defintion 1 then the question is "why? + which definition works? + why does is work?")

Addition: Is there any natural reason to avoid, for example, the usage of definition $i$, $i \ge 2$? Is there any important theorem, that works for definition $1$, but doens't work with definition $i$? I want to understand, why we should prefer one definition to another. If some definition is "bad" in some sense, then why?

Comment: Notice that for fixed $\omega $, then $\int_0^t f(s,\omega )\,\mathrm d s$ is just the Riemann (or Lebesgue depending on the regularity of $f(\cdot ,\omega )$) integral of $f(\cdot ,\omega )$ on $[0,t]$.

Comment: @Surb, ok, how will you call the situation when for fixed $\omega= \omega_0$ we consider $\int_{0}^t f(s,\omega_0)ds$?

Comment: @Surb, "But what exacltly does this term mean? : The question has no sense as well." No, it's not true. As it's written in  my question, there is more then one way to understand this notation. If you think, that my question doesn't have sense, so how do you comment the fact that different books gives different approaches to understand the sence of this integral?

Comment: @Surb, and what type of functions do you imply in the integral? Progressively measurable or not? Do you imply Riemann or Lebesgue integral?

Comment: @Surb, and why it is not the limit of Riemann sums in $L_2$, as it's written in Miller and Pankov? It's also an approach to the question: "how to understand this intergal". It looks like you ignored definitions 1 -4b.

Comment: You need at least progressively measurable and $L^1(\Omega \times [0,T])$ so that $\left(\int_0^t f(s,\cdot )ds\right)_{t\in [0,T]}$ is a stochastic process.

Comment: @Surb, so if your statement is, e.g., "Definitions 2-4b do not work, because they are not enough to derive that $\int_0^{t}$ is stoch.process", is there any counterexamples? Otherwise what is your statement about definitios 2-4b?

Comment: After, it depend what you want to do. Of course as far as $\mathbb P\{\int_0^t f(s,\cdot )ds<\infty \}=1$, then, $\int_0^t f(s,\cdot )ds$ is well define, and you don't need more, and this is more or less your definition 4b.

Comment: @Surb, of course we may use any definition and make any assumptions. But is there any natural reason to avoid, for example, the usage of definition 3? Is there any important theorem, that works for definition 1, but doens't work with definition 3? I want to understand, why we should preper one definition to another. If some definition is "bad" in some sence, then why?

Comment: If you use definition 1, then $\mathbb E\int_0^t f$ may not exist. In definition 3, I don't know what is $X_{s_i}$, I guess it's $f(t_i,\omega )$, no ? If yes, then you will have that $\int_0^t f(s,\omega )ds\in L^2$, which is very good. But definition 3 look to be a very strong definition in the sense that $\int_0^t f(s,\cdot )ds$ can be very well defined as a Riemann integral,  but I wouldn't be surprised that $\sum_{i}f(t_i;\cdot )(t_{i+1}-t_i)$ may not converges in $L^2$ (but I don't have any example). But if you allow definition 1, then definition 3 is to strict.

Comment: @Surb, in definition 3 - yes, I edited this typo. In definition 1: agree with you, such expectation may not exist, but it looks like it's the most popular definition. It's interesting if there is any simple reasons to prefer one definition to another.